# ngModel: Store as number, and optionally `null`

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

In an AngularJS/Ionic (2) web app, I'm trying to do this:

`<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="value">`

Unfortunately AngularJS stores the data as a string, and not as a number.

What's a good way of converting the value to a number, and how can I store `null` instead of an empty string (`''`) when the user did not enter anything?

Comment: but... if you define the class attribute as Number, what will be the treatment?

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo `value` is actually a property of a JSON-parsed object, like `{value: 123}`. It's not strongly typed in the app.

Comment: `if(this.value == ''){this.value = null; }`? Or are you looking for a cleaner solution?

Comment: @Ivaro18 Definitely looking for a clean solution, similar to Angular 1's parsers/formatters. I will need this really often, so doing it manually doesn't sound like a good solution to me (especially when Angular 1 was perfectly capable of it).